# Coefficient of element with some power in Polynomials with Powers

Tags: polynomials, power-series

Letʻs say I have this equation: $(x^2 + x^3 + x^4)^3$ and I want to calculate the coefficient of the element with $x^{8}$ (x power 8).

Is there a more efficient way of finding the coefficient of some element with a particular power (in my case 8), than just multiplying these polynomials with each other n times?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I thought of 8.

Comment: You may want to try the [multinomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem).

Answer (score 0):

We need the coefficient of $x^8$ in $$(x^2+x^3+x^4)^3=x^6(1+x+x^2)^3$$

$\implies$

the coefficient of $x^2$ in $$(1+x+x^2)^3$$

Now for $x\ne1,$  $$1+x+x^2=(1-x^3)(1-x)^{-1}$$

The coefficient of $x^2$ in 
$$(1+x+x^2)^3=(1-x^3)^3(1-x)^{-3}$$ will be $$1\cdot\dfrac{(-3)(-3-1)}2$$ using [Binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)

Comment: Well, I asked:
```Is there a more efficient way of finding the coefficient of some element with a particular power (in my case 8), than just multiplying these polynomials with each other n times?``` which is something very similar to what you did.

Comment: @DragosStrugar, Please find the updated answer

Comment: Thatʻs way better. What I was looking for

Comment: @Joffan, Are you talking about convergence?